# How to Execute an external link - VB 2008

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic, I want to program multiple buttons, the buttons have similar functions, and wanted to add to each button the same script, but it will give many lines for each button, so how is the same script, I want to be able to make an external link as ".VB" that communicates with the base program link ...
  Eg:

(Code of the Main Window) "JoVen.vb"

```
Public Sub Button1_Click (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
    'Code to send run External link Ai.vb
End Sub

Public Sub Button2_Click (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
    'Code to send run External link Ai.vb
End Sub
```

(Code External VB Script) "AI.vb"

```
Public Class AI
    Public Sub Main ()
         Dim But1 The New Jove ()
         But1.Bt1 = True
         MsgBox ("Link Executed")
    end Sub
end Class
```

I hope you understand me, sorry if I wrote something wrong, I'm using Google Translator.

Comment: I'm not quite understand about external link, but about the same script on every button event, is stand-alone `function` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple button controls be handled by the same click event handler, like this:

```
Public Sub Button_Click (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
    ' Common code that all buttons need here
Dnd Sub
```

Now you will not have to "repeat" the logic for a bunch of button click event handlers.

Comment: Thank you! I liked the posts, helped me a lot with something else I needed help, but I'm still with my problem. In this case, each button has a different function, but mostly as the script of the button has the same function ... Ie button1 has a specific function and more function that has the second button ...

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use handles at the end of your object procedure like

```
Public Sub Button_Click (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
```